# Is Var(sample min) decreasing in sample size?

Tags: variance, order-statistics, extreme-value

Suppose $z_n=\min\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ where $x_i$'s are i.i.d. according to CDF $F$ over $[0,1]$.

Is it true that $Var(z_n)>Var(z_{n+1})$? What conditions would I need to ensure this monotonic relationship?

Comment: Obviously the minimum is monotonically non-increasing as n increases. But that does not indicate that its variance will be non-increasing, A large drop in $x_n$ relative the minimum of the first n-1 $x_i$s could cause the sample variance to increase.

Comment: Hmm I am not talking about sample variance though. I'm defining $z_n$ as a random variable, and I'm wondering whether the population variance of $z_n$ could be monotone in $n$.

Comment: Yes I know that.  I am trying to find a way to use the fact the  $G_n(x)$= 1-(1-F(x))$^n$ where F(x) is the distribution for each X and $G_n(x)$ is the minimum of the Xs.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I've been thinking about that too. Another fact to note is that the $E[z_n]=\frac{n}{n+1}E[z_{n+1}]+\frac{1}{n+1}E[x_{2:n+1}]$, where $x_{2:n+1}$ is the second order statistic out of $n+1$ draws. The same formula would apply to $E[z_n^2]$, and I was hoping to use this fact to show the result...

Comment: The same question was asked on the mathematics site but without an answer thus far.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the math site?

Comment: I think that the answer is no. The min can be replaced by max in the
question; taking $F(x) := x^\alpha$ for $\alpha > 0$ we get
$\text{Var}(x) = \alpha / (\alpha + 1)^2 / (\alpha+2)$. The cdf of
$z_n$ is $G(z) := z^{n \alpha}$, with the same form. When $\alpha$ is
close to $0$, the variance of $z_n$ does not decrease with $n$. As a
guess, log-concavity of the distribution of $x_1$ could be a
sufficient condition.